# Unity string replacement

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, filter, replace

I am having a bit of an issue with unity engine.
I am trying to incorporate a way to replace a string from another string.
If I use a string, set as you normally would, the code works (e.g. string b = "whatever");
But when I try to use a variable from a list, the output is not getting modified (e.g. excludedWords[0]).
I have tried to transfrom it to string in all the location for my excludedWords variable but still no success.

Any insights?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;

public class FilterRex : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<string> excludedWords;
    [SerializeField]TextAsset excludedWordsFile;

    [SerializeField]TMP_InputField inputField;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //this code accesses the words from the lists that need to be banned
        excludedWords = new List<string>();
        string[] lines = excludedWordsFile.text.Split('\n');
        foreach(string line in lines)
        {

            excludedWords.Add(line);
        }
        Debug.Log(excludedWords[0]);
        
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            PrepareTheWord();
        }
    }

    public void PrepareTheWord()
    {
            string innerWord = inputField.text.ToLower();
            string b = excludedWords[0].ToString());
            inputField.text = ReplaceTheWord(b, innerWord);
    }
    public string ReplaceTheWord(string _replace, string _from)
    {
        string output = _from.Replace(_replace, "");
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Input.GetKeyDown` I would rather use e.g. [`onValueChanged`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-onValueChanged.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for a quick fix. I have noticed that if I create an array and I type down the elements of that array it will work. Is not the most eficient way, and neither the pleasant, but it will do the job for the time being.

On another note. I am not sure if this is a issue with unity, but I am sure that is not an issue with the PC. I have tested this code already on three different pc with different unity releases from 2019. And they all seem to behave the same.
I am sure I will discover the issue, but for the time being, I will be focusing on other updates.
I want to thank everyone who read and responded to my enquire and I am wishing all of you a good day!

I have tested unity 2018 version, still same same issue, made with a new project.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mutate a string value in a list, you will need to assign to it directly:

```cs
excludedWords[0] = ReplaceTheWord(excludedWords[0], innerWord);
```

Strings in C# are immutable, so if you want to change their value, you must reassign to them.

Edit:
If you want to replace occurrences of the excluded words in the input text, here is what your `PrepareTheWord` method might look like:

```cs
public void PrepareTheWord()
{
    string innerWord = inputField.text.ToLower();

    foreach (string excludedWord in excludedWords)
    {
        innerWord = innerWord.Replace(excludedWord, "");
    }

    inputField.text = innerWord;
}
```

This is not the most efficient way, but it should do the job.

Comment: I have tested your idea and I am getting an ArgumentException: oldValue is the empty string. Again, if I am writing directly ReplaceTheWord("theWordThatIWant", innerWorld); will work.

Comment: On top of that I do not want to change the string in excludedWords. They are only as reference to be checked against

Comment: Then I'm really not sure what you're asking. Do you just want `b = ReplaceTheWord(b, innerWord); inputField.text = b;`?

Comment: I want to do a check against excludedWords[0]. The inputField has a word introduced by the user. When I click enter, I am running this function. This function gets the input. In ReplaceTheWord, I am checking against a list. If in the list there is a word that can be found in inputField, then I remove it, leaving behind only the rest of the word.

Comment: I have just noticed that: string[] = {"word1", "word2"} is not equal with the list that I made: excludedWords[0] and excludedWords[1]. I am looking right now at deferred execution, but I am not sure if that is it

Comment: When I am using debug.log I definitely don't see a difference. Both of the words look the same

Comment: Ok, so for example, say the user enters `"hello"` into `inputField.text`, and we'll say that `excludedWords` has the values `["he", "she", "they"]`. You would then want the result of the operation to be that `inputField.text` is now `"llo"`?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want! But for whatever reason, when I am using excludedWords[0], is like not detecting the element; but when debugged is showing exactly what I want

Comment: Tested. Every bit of code runs perfectly until it reaches Replace. For whatever reason is not working, the output is the same input that I have typed  in for the first time

Comment: Are you certain that there are matches within `excludedWords`? Also note that `Replace` is case-sensitive, and you're converting the input text to lowercase.

Comment: Yes, I am certain. If I debug.log the excludedWord I am getting all the words that would be excluded. From the original file, all words are lowercase, that is the reason why I am getting the input to be lowercase. The excluded word file is a .txt if that might help?!

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is then, because it worked for me in LINQPad. However, I am not familiar with the `TMP_InputField` type.